# Inconsistent Outputs from uuid_to_bin() in MySQL vs. Percona XtraDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, uuid, percona-xtradb-cluster

I'm currently working with both MySQL and Percona XtraDB Cluster and have encountered a curious difference in the behavior of `uuid_to_bin()` and `bin_to_uuid()` functions across these two systems.

- I am using MySQL version 8.1.0 (for my local) and Percona XtraDB Cluster version 5.7.39-42-57-log (for production).
- My work involves handling UUIDs in both environments.

For example, the query `select uuid_to_bin('01ae07f7-8513-11ee-98f4-0242ac110005')` produces different outputs in MySQL and Percona XtraDB Cluster. It makes it harder to debug in different environments.

Why does this query yield different results in MySQL and Percona XtraDB Cluster?

Comment: What do they produce?  If you're doing cross-platform stuff you probably want to deal with them as strings, anyway.

Comment: I can't copy the result (maybe because it binary types), I can attach screenshot, can't I?

Comment: The column is binary; when I want to debug it, I convert it into a string using `bin_to_uuid()`, but it produces different results in production and localhost.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `uuid_to_bin()` and `bin_to_uuid()` are not implemented as builtin functions in Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.7. I'm looking at the source code: https://github.com/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster/blob/5.7/sql/item_strfunc.cc and code for these two functions is not present, whereas it is present in that code file in the 8.0 branch. I'm wondering if someone implemented the functions as stored functions. Can you please run this query: `SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME='uuid_to_bin';`

Comment: You really should use the same version of software in development as you will deploy to in production. You're liable to run into other incompatibilities like this. It's not fun to spend time developing software that depends on features that aren't supported in your production environment.

Comment: I seeeee, it is really not built in function, someone made that function. yeaah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above, it seems someone has used `CREATE FUNCTION` on the Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.7 instance to create a function named `uuid_to_bin`, but their implementation is slightly incompatible from the builtin function of the same name added in MySQL 8.0.

This causes confusion because your uses of that function in your development instance gets different results than they do in production. The function exists by the same name, but it's a different function.

It's important to use the same version of database software in development and testing as you will use in production. Every release includes many changes, new features, or even feature removal. Some of these changes are harmless, but others cause incompatibility.

You don't want to waste your time using a feature that is present in a newer version, and then deploy to an older version in production and get a surprise that the feature is not implemented in the older version. That's frustrating and more importantly, it can cause issues because you have to undo some code you had already thought was done. Your employer won't be happy with the time wasted.

So you should develop and test with the same version of software that you run in production, as much as possible.